# Android AlarmManager - ELAPSED_REALTIME alarm continues repeating when sleep

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I work on Nexus 4 - Android 4.3 - api_18.

When I schedule a `PendingIntent` using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME`, the alarm continues calling my `BroadcastReceiver` when the device is in sleep mode.

Documentation says that when device goes to sleep, the `BroadcastReceiver` is called only once and then when device wakes up :

> If it goes off while the device is asleep, it will not be delivered until 
>   the next time the device wakes up.

In my case, `BroadcastReceiver` is repeatedly called when device is asleep.

My code

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 
                          SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 
                          DELAI_PLANNIF_TICK, 
                          pendingIntent);
```

Comment: How do you know that your device goes to sleep mode?

Comment: Hi, good question, I only turn off the screen with the button on the device. And when the screen is off and I get the tick, I test : pm.isScreenOn() and it's false. I suppose that the device is in sleep mode then ?

Comment: During sleep mode the CPU is in low power state and thus not executing code (subject to be woken up by an alarm), it usually happens a few seconds after the screen is off.

Comment: Hi, ok, I'll track that with the logcat and I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

When you turn your screen off, Android is not in Sleep mode. It is going there and this process can take more than a few seconds. Some apps may obtain a `WakeLock` and continue their tasks when screen is off (e.g. playing audio). My guess is that your device is just not in sleep mode and you `BroadcastReceiver`'s behavior is as expected. If you don't work with `PowerManager`, then you should not worry about preventing device from going to sleep. If your app needs to stop execution when user doesn't interact with device, it is better to handle screen of event.

Comment: Hi, I've tested for two hours and I confirm that after the terminal go to sleep (and I've verified that it's in sleep mode), the BroadcastReceiver is continually called. Otherwise, handle the screen off event is a good substitution idea.